# Having trouble doubling the size of a dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a function that adds integers to an array. If space runs out it should double the array size and add the value at the next free spot. So if the array size is 3 for example and I enter 99, 105, and 45. Now if I want to add 100 a new array of size 6 should be created. There is a snippet of the code below.  It all works and I even display array[4] within the local function it returns 100. When the program returns to main to display the menu again all the values become -572662307. I spent days attempting to figure this out but could not. can anyone help?

```
    //Snippet from Main

    cout<<"Enter the size of the array to be created";
    cin >> size;
    int *myArray = new int[size]();
    add(myArray,Size);

    //Problematic Code 
    void add (int Array[], int size){
       int* temp = new int[size*2]; // create new Array 2x The Size

       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           temp[i] = Array[i];//Copy data over
       }


       delete [] Array;//Delete the old array
       Array = temp;

       cout << "\n\nEnter a Number: ";
       cin >> newNumber;

       Array[sizeTrack] = newNumber;
       sizeTrack = sizeTrack++;
```

Comment: Doesn't `std::vector` solve these kind of problems?

Comment: Please provide an actual *runnable* example, not snippets (that don't even work, since you use e.g. `size` and `Size` in the first few lines) and open-ended functions.

Comment: C++ uses pass by value, unless you specify pass by reference (which you didn't). `Array = temp` in the function has no effect on `myArray` in main

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array", you next thought should *always* be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The assignment says to use Arrays, and Im not sure if I should post my entire assignment online, thats why I only posted the code thats causing issues.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a school assignment and you can't use `std::vector`, then you need to know that by declaring an argument as `int Array[]`, it's really the same as `int* Array`. What you have is a *pointer*, and when calling the function you pass a *copy* of the pointer.

That last part is important: You pass a *copy* of the value in the variable. That means, when you modify the argument variable inside the function, you only modify the *copy*. And modifying a copy leaves the original unmodified.

There are two possible solutions here, both which you should either already know about (go through your text-books and class notes) or should be able to find in your text-book:

1. *Returning* the new pointer.
2. Passing the argument *by reference*.

Comment: Or pass a pointer to the pointer: `void add (int **Array, int size)`  Then when you change *Array the right thing happens (I know that the code will be unmaintainably messy...)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah With C++ it's not really needed to use such C-ish hacks to *emulate* pass by reference. C++ have native references.

Comment: I am still having trouble, I read what you said and I think I understand but cannot get the right syntax. Either Visual Studio continues to give the same output or wont compile because argument int** is not compatible with int *** or some variation of that error

Comment: @Wavvey213 Please don't listen to the comment by Jerry, it's ill-advised. If you don't want to return the new pointer, then use *references*. You *have* used it before? With the `&` before a variable name? Like (in your case) `int*& Array`? If you don't know what it means, ***read your books***.